# Polymer 1.0 data binding on custom element for pagination

Tags: data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I am learning Polymer to make a small single page app.
I would like to manage pagination as it is done in the Polymer starter kit, but without using the  **template dom-bind** (because I need one later in the page, and we cannot have one nested in another).

So, I tried to make my own custom element in order to bind its attribute "route" to the **iron-pages** element. But, as you can imagine, it did not work.

So I tried to make data binding work in a small example. As shown in the "Quick Tour of Polymer", I have made a custom element in "pagination-element.html" :

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "pagination-element",
    properties:{
      route : {type:String, value:"/", notify : true}
    }
  });
</script>
```

and using it in my page (I have checked that *pagination-element.html* is imported) :

```
<pagination-element id="app" route="/">
    <paper-input label="{{ route }}"></paper-input>
</pagination-element>
```

Then, I tried to get the "route" value with an other Polymer custom element, but it only displays me "{{route}}" on my page.

I think I have not understood how data binding works...

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

On your page you will need to wrap your `pagination-element` in an [auto binding template](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-bind) using (unless you are using this inside another element):

```
<template is="dom-bind">
```

In your `paper-input` you are setting the `label` to be the value of `route` but you have not given `route` a value. I'm guessing you want the value of it to be that of the `route` property on the `pagination-element`:

So in your `index.html` or other page:

```
<body unresolved>
    <template is="dom-bind">
        <pagination-element id="app" route="{{route}}">
            <paper-input label="{{route}}"></paper-input>
        </pagination-element>
    </template>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, but I would like to avoid using a dom-bind template because I need one later in my page, and we can't use it nested.

Comment: As I understand the Polymer doc : _"To use Polymer bindings without defining a new custom element, use the dom-bind element"_, we could bind data between custom elements without using the dom-bind.

Comment: Why can't you just have one `dom-bind` for the whole page? To data-bind between the custom elements on your index.html you **do** need to wrap this in a dom-bind. You can see this is how it is done in the [Polymer starter kit](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/app/index.html)